# Chrome is getting a forced popup to redirect to a website hosted by optimize-app.com

Tags: google-chrome, redirection

I get a popup on my chrome from company saying I've won a prize.

It's modal to the whole of chrome, and whether you click the cross or the OK button it forcible redirects me to another page.  Is this a hack running on chrome or should I be worried about something installed on my local chrome.

I'm running windows 8.1 if it's relevant.

Comment: go to extensions remove unwanted extensions which will relieve u from most annoying popups

Answer (score -1):

I believe that this is caused by the autorefresh extension. You should remove it by going to the extensions menu.